# An unusual and very hard number sequence problem

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

I heard this number sequence problem about 25 years ago from a maths lecturer.

What number should go in the place of the question mark in this mathematical sequence:

..., 30, ?, 60, 90, 140, 225, 372, 630, ...

I generally dislike number sequence puzzles, but the (intended) answer to this puzzle is so surprising that I feel it should be more widely known. I don't know the origin of this puzzle, so it would be great if anyone has any info on it.

If nobody gets anywhere with it, I will start dropping hints in the comments below to get the ball rolling.

Comment: You say "Surprising". Is the answer an integer?

Comment: @IAmInPLS No comment :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Okay, I found something.

We must consider :

> the numbers as $a_n$, with $n = -1,..., 6$ thus $a_0$ is the one we're supposed to find.

We have :

> $a_{-1} = 30$
>  $a_0 = ?$
>  $a_1 = 60$
>  $a_2 = 90$
>  $a_3 = 140$
>  $a_4 = 225$
>  $a_5 = 372$
>  $a_6 = 630$

Then :

> If we look at the sequence $n*a_n$, we get :
>  $-1*a_{-1} = -30$
>  $?$
>  $1*a_1 = 60$
>  $2*a_2 = 180$
>  $3*a_3 = 420$
>  $4*a_4 = 900$
>  $5*a_5 = 1860$
>  $6*a_6 = 3780$
>  For $n>0$, these numbers are all divisible by 60, so let's divide them by 60 :
>  $\frac{1*a_1}{60} = 1$
>  $\frac{2*a_2}{60} = 3$
>  $\frac{3*a_3}{60} = 7$
>  $\frac{4*a_4}{60} = 15$
>  $\frac{5*a_5}{60} = 31$
>  $\frac{6*a_6}{60} = 63$
>  which are the famous [Mersenne numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), and can be noted : $b_n=2^n - 1$

Thus :

> For $n>0$, we have : $n*a_n = 60*b_n$

Finally :

> It works for $a_{-1}$ also, since $-1*a_{-1} = -30 = 60*(2^{-1}-1) = 60*(1/2-1)$.
>
>
> **I think that @Etoplay found the final answer**, nonetheless I will add it here in order to have a full answer written.
>
> The formula to find the values $a_n$ is thus : $a_n = h(n) = \frac{60\dot{}b_n}{n} = \frac{60\dot{}(2^n-1)}{n}$, and we are looking for $h(0)$.
>
> We can now use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) with $f(n) = 60\dot{}(2^n-1)$ and $g(n) = n$. We have :
>
> $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} h(n) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(n)}{g'(n)}$
>
>
> With $f'(n) = 2^x\dot{}ln(2)$, using the fact that $2^x = (e^{ln(2)})^x = e^{x\dot{}ln(2)}$ and $g'(n) = 1$, we find that :
>
> $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} h(n) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{60\dot{}ln(2)\dot{}2^x}{1} = 60\dot{}ln(2)$

And the answer is :

> $a_0 = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow 0} h(n) = 60\dot{}ln(2) \approx 41,588$, which is the number to be found instead of the question mark in the question.
>
>   We can see it on this plot of $h$, courtesy of @Chris in the comments :
>
>  [image]

Comment: The numbers you have are different from the numbers in the question...?

Comment: @IAmInPLS I think you should clarify that you are talking about the sequence  $a_-1$, $a_0$, $a_1$, etc. Unfortunately I don't know how to add index -1.

Comment: @hexomino Just edited ;)

Comment: Okay cool. Looks good to me.

Comment: @IAmInPLS: Now that you focus on the n>0 terms, why not divide by 60? It makes the resulting sequence more recognisable, so you don't need OEIS for it.

Comment: Don't know why I was so focused on 30!

Comment: These are not the Mersenne prime numbers: 15 and 63 are not in them and aren't even prime. This is simply the series $2^n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to remove the prime. These are only the Mersenne numbers.

Comment: Radoslav, for "compound" subscripts or superscripts you put them in curly braces: \$a\_{-1}\$ becomes $a_{-1}$.

Comment: Well done! I have accepted your answer. Although Etoplay came up with the final part, I know you got there first and edited it out again to give other people a go. :-)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thank you! Yes, special thanks to him for the final answer. It was a fun and challenging puzzle!

Answer (score 14):

Based on the other answers the formula for the values is $f(x)=$

> $\frac{60\dot{}(2^x-1)}{x}$

(with the first value is for $x=-1$).

The question is what is $f(0)$.

> If we assume that $f$ is continuous then we get with the help of L'Hospital's Rule:
> $f(0) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{60\dot{}(2^x-1)}{x} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{60\dot{}ln(2)\dot{}2^x}{1} = 60\dot{}ln(2) \approx 41.5888$

Comment: A plot of this graph agrees with this answer: http://fooplot.com/plot/qvgxtkycxa

Answer (score 6):

I'd say:

> **Any** number can go in the place of the question mark!

Let's index the numbers $a_{n}$, $-1 \le n \le 6$, with $a_0$ the missing one.

Now let's look at the following table:

| n | -1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a<sub>n</sub> | 30 | ? | 60 | 90 | 140 | 225 | 372 | 630 |
| n * a<sub>n</sub> | -30 | 0*? | 60 | 180 | 420 | 900 | 1860 | 3780 |
| 60 * (2<sup>n</sup> - 1) | -30 | 0 | 60 | 180 | 420 | 900 | 1860 | 3780 |

> So the sequence can be defined as $n \cdot a_n = 60 \cdot (2^n - 1)$, and this holds **whatever the question mark is** (because $0 \cdot ? = 0$).

(This of course builds on IAmInPLS's answer, but as he didn't quite get there I allowed myself to put my own version.)

Comment: Last row there should be a 0 instead of a ?

Comment: @Etoplay You're right! Fixed. (BTW, nice answer of your own.)

Answer (score 0):

I picked up the pattern that for all the known terms in the sequence,
***calculating the log of a term with the base being the term that proceeds it will be approximately equal to 1.09***, losing it's degree of accuracy of 1.09 the bigger the terms are. Thus, I found my answer to be approximately ***42***.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn another badge? For number sequence patterns we tend to prefer answers with a definitive conclusion, but it's nice to see you've had a go! (Hint: the actual answer is within that range, and there's a reason for the correlation.) Hope you can go on to post more answers!

Answer (score -3):

$30\times2=60$
$2\times x+y=90$
$60\times2+20=140$
$90\times2+45=225$
$140\times2+92=372$
$225\times2+180=630$

y,20,45,92,180
$2\times y+5=20$
$20\times2+5=45$
$45\times2+2=92$
$92\times2-4=180$

$y=7.5$
$2\times x+7.5=90$
$x=41.25$

Comment: 302 never equals 60. Please explain what's going on with your answer, it seems almost completely unrelated to the problem

Comment: @Cotton Did you miss the `*`? This answer is giving an algorithm for constructing the sequence. I'm not sure if it's right or wrong, but 30 times 2 equals 60 is correct at least.

Comment: The *’s where not there last I saw it, but they are now

Answer (score -4):

Thinking logically the answer should be 45.
Bcoz if we consider the alternative terms then the series follows this pattern:

630-225= 405
225-90= 135
Hence let the missing to term be x.
Here Everytime the difference is the multiple of 3.
Hence for alternative numbers x should be 45.
90-45 = 45.